# SPSS: How do I generate ID numbers from client ID variable that contains duplicate IDs

Tags: duplicates, spss, uniqueidentifier

I have a dataset which contains thousands of rows which each person assigned a ClientID. I would like to use the ClientID variable to generate a new ID variable which starts at 1. Some ClientIDs are duplicated so I would like to make sure that duplicate ClientIDs are given the same ID number. Client IDs are string and my data has to be sorted by TimeStamp.

My data looks like:

```
ClientID TimeStamp

15137.45692 15/03/2021

10489.15789 03/02/2021

14143.96745 01/01/2021

15137.45692 15/01/2021

15137.45692 27/02/2021

14143.96745 08/03/2021
```

I would like it to look like:

```
ID ClientID TimeStamp

1 14143.96745 01/01/2021
    
2 15137.45692 15/01/2021
    
3 10489.15789 03/02/2021
    
2 15137.45692 27/02/2021
    
1 14143.96745 08/03/2021
    
2 15137.45692 15/03/2021
```

How do I do this?

I would do it in excel but I have over 250k rows of data and excel keeps crashing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following syntax creates ID=1 and then adds 1 only in case of a new ClientID:

```
sort cases by ClientID.
compute ID=1.
if $casenum>1 ID=lag(ID)+(ClientID<>lag(ClientID)).
exe.
```

**EDIT:**
Here's another nice way to do it using `rank` function:

```
RANK VARIABLES=ClientID (A) /RANK /PRINT=NO /TIES=CONDENSE.
```

Comment: I have had another look at this and i'm not sure it works for my dataset. My rows need to be sorted by timestamp. How do I assign the same clientID the same ID number if they don't appear next to each other in the dataset?

Comment: My second solution using `rank` doesn't require sorting. But also for my first solution - when you're done with calculating the new `ID` you can just re-sort the data by timestamp without a problem.

Comment: The issue I have with the Rank function is that my ClientID is a string and it has to be string because some IDs are not all numerical. So when I try to use your second solution I get an error unfortunately. And I could re-sort using your first solution but then IDs are in a weird order which I guess isn't necessarily a problem. I just wonder if there is a way for my data to look exactly like I have it in the post?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242572/discussion-between-eli-k-and-duncan-talbot).